# How to print sid value in webform?

Tags: 7, webforms

I have created a form using [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module, and alter form In D7

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  global $user;

  if('webform_client_form_1' == $form_id) {

    $form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_check_email';   

  }

}

function mymodule_check_email($form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

.............

.............

}
```

I write `print_r($form_state);` in **mymodule_check_email** function.

Get all variables but **sid** value is empty but in database sid insert proper.

My question how to get **sid** value.

Comment: Which version of webform are you using ??

Comment: webform 7.x-3.19

Answer (score 1):

The sid won't be available from a validation handler; validation handlers are called before form submission, thus a valid sid for your submission doesn't exist at time of execution.

If you need to call a post-submit webform hander, the [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module provides [`hook_webform_submission_insert()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!webform.api.php/function/hook_webform_submission_insert/7):

```
function mymodule_webform_submission_insert($node, $submission) {
  // The submission object contains $submission->sid, the submission id.
  print_r($submission);
}
```

Comment: yes, this is right answer vote up.